# How to provide validation

Tags: vue.js, core-ui

> I have this type of templete i want to provide validation using vuejs.
>   Can any one help me   or complete the code with validation,  I am a
>   learner and new to vue js.plz complete the validation I dont know how
>   to validate CFrom How to Apply validation on this type of from using
>   vuejs 
>   Login.vue

```
<template>
      <CContainer class="d-flex content-center min-vh-100">
        <CRow>
          <CCol>
            <CCardGroup>
              <CCard class="p-4">
                <CCardBody>
                  <CForm>
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                    <CInput
                      placeholder="Username"
                      autocomplete="username email"
                    >
                      <template #prepend-content><CIcon name="cil-user"/></template>
                    </CInput>
                    <CInput
                      placeholder="Password"
                      type="password"
                      autocomplete="curent-password"
                    >
                      <template #prepend-content><CIcon name="cil-lock-locked"/></template>
                    </CInput>
                    <CRow>
                      <CCol col="6" class="text-left">
                        <CButton color="primary" class="px-4">Login</CButton>
                      </CCol>
                      <CCol col="6" class="text-right">
                        <CButton color="link" class="px-0">Forgot password?</CButton>
                        <CButton color="link" class="d-md-none">Register now!</CButton>
                      </CCol>
                    </CRow>
                  </CForm>
                </CCardBody>
              </CCard>
              <CCard
                color="primary"
                text-color="white"
                class="text-center py-5 d-sm-down-none"
                body-wrapper
              >
                <h2>Sign up</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <CButton
                  color="primary"
                  class="active mt-3"
                >
                  Register Now!
                </CButton>
              </CCard>
            </CCardGroup>
          </CCol>
        </CRow>
      </CContainer>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'Login'
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, manually managing all your validations would become a cumbersome task as your application would grow. Why don't you consider using some external library for this. You can probably use v-validate.

Comment: I know validation,but i dont  know how to validate this type of  from,

Comment: What all validation rules would you want for these fields? I hope you're trying for client side validation and not server side validation